# GST prices, selling price and cost price

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Just wondering if I have done the following question correctly.

3 people paid $459 (including GST) for a flight to Perth. Calculate the GST.

I have worked that the selling price is $459 (obviously) so the cost price would  be 459*0.15=68.86, then 459-68.85 which equals 390.15 (I suspect this is wrong).

For the GST i just subtracted the cost price from the selling price. (Is this the correct thing to do).

Just wondering if what I did is correct. If not, it would be great if you could correct me and explain what it was that I did wrong.

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 2):

Given that selling price is \$459 and assuming that GST (service tax ) is 15%. your equation should become something similar to this :

cost price(base ) + cost price * 0.15(tax which should be calculated from cost price) = selling price (459$ in our case).

so cost price = selling price / 1.15 => 459 / 1.15 =>399.135 (which is our cost price).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but where did you get the 1.15 from? I am just not sure about the cost price times 0.15

Comment: Christopher, if we take cost price common from the above equation :
we get costprice(1 + 0.15(15% service tax)) = costprice * (1.15). 

Hence we get that 1.15.

cost price * 0.15 is because any extra taxes are included on the base price which in turn returns defines the selling price accumilating all taxes.